# Importing a room schedule calendar from a public folder

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I import a room schedule calendar from a public folder in Outlook and identify what times are available for each room given date/time range?

I looked at some examples online but they give occupied times not available times.

Can I query Mapi namespace to get this information?

Comment: You can get *help* here, but typically folk will not write your code - if you have any code already, your chances of an answer are much improved by posting it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! Figured it out..used the mapi name space to pull the olAppointments and load to a 2d array and did the operation on that to determine available time blocks.